# Robot not spawning in initial pose set in the launch file

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-noetic

I have a mobile robot(husky) with two UR5 manipulators on top of it. I have set the initial joint angles in the launch file but the robot does not go to that pose when I run Gazebo. I don't know if the URDF has to do something with this. Please help resolve this so that the robot spawns with the right joint angles. Following is my launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Start gazebo -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find husky_dual_ur5_config)/worlds/apple_rosbag.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Load the URDF into the ROS parameter server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find husky_dual_ur5_description)/urdf/husky_dual_ur5.urdf.xacro'"/>


  
  <!-- Spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_husky_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
    args="-x 0.0
          -y 0.0
          -z 0.1
          -Y 0.0
          -J r_ur5_arm_shoulder_pan_joint -1.57 
          -J r_ur5_arm_shoulder_lift_joint -0.1745 
          -J r_ur5_arm_elbow_joint -2.1
          -J r_ur5_arm_wrist_1_joint -1.57 
          -J r_ur5_arm_wrist_2_joint 0.0 
          -J r_ur5_arm_wrist_3_joint 0.0 
          -J l_ur5_arm_shoulder_pan_joint -1.57
          -J l_ur5_arm_shoulder_lift_joint -0.1745
          -J l_ur5_arm_elbow_joint -2.1
          -J l_ur5_arm_wrist_1_joint -1.57
          -J l_ur5_arm_wrist_2_joint 0.0
          -J l_ur5_arm_wrist_3_joint 0.0
          -urdf
          -param robot_description
          -model vaultbot
          -gazebo_namespace gazebo
          "/>
<!-- Load the robot's controllers and drivers -->
  <include file="$(find husky_dual_ur5_config)/launch/husky_dual_ur5_nav_driver.launch" />
  <include file="$(find husky_dual_ur5_config)/launch/husky_dual_ur5_nav_controller.launch" />
  <include file="$(find husky_dual_ur5_config)/launch/husky_dual_ur5_manip_driver.launch" />
  <include file="$(find husky_dual_ur5_config)/launch/husky_dual_ur5_manip_controller.launch" />


</launch>
```